# how to split a given range by unix command

Tags: unix

I have a string as say `x..y`.

I want an output having `x` and `y`. `x` and `y` may be an integer or floating number.

How to achieve this using shell script? I tried for integer using this command:

```
a21=`echo $a2 | cut -d'.' -f1`
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you wanted. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any one of the string processing languages like `awk` / `sed`.

Here is an `awk` example:

```
echo 1.234..5.678 | awk -F[.][.] '{print $1,$2,":",$0}'
```

You can obviously change the `print` statement to get rid of the input (`$0`) in that line

```
echo 1.234..5.678 | awk -F[.][.] '{print $1,$2}'
```

Comment: How to do this in c @andy

Comment: @ursandy if you are done, remember you can accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @usrandy - sorry I am not a c-coder. Could hack something up, but I honestly hack around mostly in Perl / Sed / Awk / Ruby. Perhaps someone else could give you a neat answer

Comment: Thanks - this is nice